# Error in if (file.exists(file.path(saga.path, "modules"))) { :

Tags: r, saga

I am using the RSAGA package for R, I have downloaded SAGA GIS that is required to run these tools in R. I am running a couple of tools in the beginning that works or I do get output files but after I try to create raster object of slope raster I get an error code that says:

```
Error in if (file.exists(file.path(saga.path, "modules"))) { :
```

This is my env- settings:

```
dir.saga <- "C:/Program Files/saga-8.4.1_x64"

myenv=rsaga.env(workspace=work_dir,
                path="C:/Program Files/saga-8.4.1_x64",
                modules="C:/Program Files/saga-8.4.1_x64/RSAGA/man")
```

As earlier stated I am new to R :) Thank you for all the tips!
Liza

I am trying to get potential release areas for avalanches by using Rstudio and RSAGA, so everything is helpful!

Comment: Haven't used SAGA with R myself, but you might check whether "C:/Program Files/saga-8.4.1_x64/RSAGA/man" is indeed the path to the saga *modules* (as you specified in `rsaga.env(...)` )? How to check: https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/RSAGA/html/rsaga.get.modules.html

Comment: correct path entry in your `rsaga.env` probably being `modules="C:/Program Files/saga-8.4.1_x64/tools"`  or `modules="C:/Program Files/saga-8.4.1_x64/modules")` (see: https://www.quantargo.com/help/r/latest/packages/RSAGA/1.3.0/rsaga.env)

Comment: Thank you for your replies, I try to do that but then I get an error saying

`Error in rsaga.geoprocessor("ta_morphometry", 23, env = myenv, list(DEM = "outputRas.sgrd",  : 
  object 'myenv' not found`

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You did create the object `myenv` again, like in your example code `myenv = rsaga.env(...)` didn't you? This object is not permanent across R sessions.

Comment: Yes I usually run my code from the top of the script because I just had so many struggles with it... I tried to post the beginning of my code here but realised its not possible.